# Diesel generic update

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am trying implementation of a generic update method using diesel. At first I tried to pass an object

```rust
pub fn update<Model, Tab>(
    conn: &PgConnection,
    _: Tab,
    current_model: Model,
    mut new_model: Model,
) -> Result<Model, diesel::result::Error>
```

but with this there were some difficulties and I changed it to a reference.

Now i have this code:

```rust
pub fn update<'m, Model, Tab>(
    conn: &PgConnection,
    _: Tab,
    current_model: &Model,
    mut new_model: Model,
) -> Result<Model, diesel::result::Error>
where
    Model: AsChangeset<Target = Tab>
        + Insertable<Tab>
        + diesel::Queryable<<<Tab as Table>::AllColumns as diesel::Expression>::SqlType, Pg>
        + IntoUpdateTarget
        + HasTable<Table = Tab>
        + 'm
        + diesel::Queryable<
            <<<&'m Model as HasTable>::Table as Table>::AllColumns as diesel::Expression>::SqlType,
            Pg,
        >
        + AsChangeset<Target = Tab>,
    &'m Model: Identifiable + IntoUpdateTarget,
    <<&'m Model as HasTable>::Table as QuerySource>::FromClause: QueryFragment<Pg>,
    <&'m Model as IntoUpdateTarget>::WhereClause: QueryFragment<Pg>,
    Pg: HasSqlType<
        <<<&'m Model as HasTable>::Table as Table>::AllColumns as diesel::Expression>::SqlType,
    >,
    <<&'m Model as HasTable>::Table as Table>::AllColumns: QueryFragment<Pg>,
    &'m Model: AsChangeset,
    <&'m Model as AsChangeset>::Changeset: QueryFragment<Pg>,
    <Model as AsChangeset>::Changeset: QueryFragment<Pg>,
    <Model as IntoUpdateTarget>::WhereClause: QueryFragment<Pg>,

    Tab: HasTable<Table = Tab> + Table + IntoUpdateTarget + FindDsl<Model>,
    <Tab as QuerySource>::FromClause: QueryFragment<Pg>,
    <Tab as IntoUpdateTarget>::WhereClause: QueryFragment<Pg>,
    <Tab as Table>::AllColumns: QueryFragment<Pg>,
{

    Ok(diesel::update(current_model)
        .set(new_model)
        .get_result(conn)
        .unwrap())
}
```

But when compiling, it gives such an error and I don’t quite understand what’s wrong and how best to fix it.

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<Model as AsChangeset>::Target == <&Model as HasTable>::Table`
   |
38 | pub fn update<'m, Model, Tab>(
   |                          --- this type parameter
...
78 |         .set(new_model)
   |          ^^^ expected associated type, found type parameter `Tab`
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<&Model as HasTable>::Table`
               found type parameter `Tab`
   = note: you might be missing a type parameter or trait bound
note: required by a bound in `UpdateStatement::<T, U>::set`
   |
43 |         V: changeset::AsChangeset<Target = T>,
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `UpdateStatement::<T, U>::set`
```

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be solved? And is it possible to implement an abstract update over a diesel engine at all, maybe someone has implemented something similar. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As a general advice: Avoid writing generic code in that way to "abstract" over diesel. It is quite hard to write this code as diesel is opinionated about it's API. If you feel that something is hard to abstract over it is a quite clear sign that you likely head into the wrong direction. In this case you seem to exchange the builder based pattern diesel uses to a single function call. Both require exactly the same information and I would say both are similar "hard" to type. So maybe just use that variant diesel already provides?

That written: It is certainly possible to implement such a function. It requires to fulfill any trait bound rustc requests. I generally advice to not only look at the first bound rustc advice to add, but also on the `required because of:` lines, because often they contain the same trait bound in different messages. Adding this shared bound allows to simplify the relevant code.

To fix the error messages contained in your question in just need to add the following bounds:

```rust
pub fn update<Model, Tab>(
    conn: &PgConnection,
    table: Tab,
    mut new_model: Model,
) -> Result<Usize, diesel::result::Error>
where
    Model: AsChangeset<Target = Tab> + Insertable<Tab>,
    Tab: Identifiable
        + QueryFragment<Pg>
        + HasTable<Table = Tab>
        + diesel::Table
        + IntoUpdateTarget
        + AsChangeset,
     <Tab as QuerySource>::FromClause: QueryFragment<Pg>,
     <Tab as IntoUpdateTarget>::WhereClause: QueryFragment<Pg>,
     <Model as AsChangeset>::Changeset: QueryFragment<Pg>,
{ … }
```

Comment: Of course I can use the option that diesel offers, but the abstraction will give me many advantages that will make it easier to further design the application.