# More generic CRUD. RUST, Diesel

Tags: postgresql, rust, orm, rust-diesel

is it possible to create more generic queries using diesel?
I know how to create update or delete for every properties. But my point is create generic update for many structures.
My models:

```
#[derive(Associations, Identifiable, Queryable, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[diesel(belongs_to(User))]
#[diesel(table_name = books)]
pub struct Book {
    pub id: i32,
    pub user_id: i32,
    pub title: String,
    pub body: String,
    pub book_description: String,
    pub book_image: Option<String>,
    pub publish_day: chrono::NaiveDateTime,
}

#[derive(Associations, Identifiable, Queryable, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[diesel(belongs_to(Book))]
#[diesel(table_name = book_comments)]
pub struct BookComment {
    pub id: i32,
    pub book_id: i32,
    pub body: String,    
    pub publish_day: chrono::NaiveDateTime,
}
```

My schema:

```
diesel::table! {
    books (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        user_id -> Int4,
        title -> Varchar,
        body -> Text,
        book_description -> Varchar,
        book_image -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        publish_day -> Timestamp,
    }
}

diesel::table! {
    book_comments (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        book_id -> Int4,
        body -> Varchar,
        publish_day -> Timestamp,
    }
}
```

Working wersion:

```
pub fn upate<T>(&mut self, book_id: &i32, title: &str) -> Book {
        let result = diesel::update(books::table)
            .filter(book::id.eq(&book_id))
            .set(book::title.eq(title))
            .get_result::<Book>(&mut self.connection)
            .expect("Failed to update book");

        result
    }
```

I'm trying something like this:

```
 pub fn upate<T, U, P: Table, S>(&mut self, find_by: &T, change: U, target_table: Table,change_param: &S) -> Book {
        let result = diesel::update(target_table)
            .filter(find_by.eq(&book_id))
            .set(S.eq(change))
            .get_result::<U>(&mut self.connection)
            .expect("Failed to update book");

        result
```

But of course doesn't work. Is this possible?

Little help with solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diesel generic update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73460931/diesel-generic-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this using macro, this is a snippet from the code I used

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! get_by_id {
    ($table:ident,$m:ident,$pool:ident,$id:ident) => {
         {
            let conn = $pool.get()?;
            let res = $table::table
                .filter($table::columns::id.eq($id))
                .get_result::<$m>(&conn)?;
            Ok(res) as Result<$m, Error>
        }
    };
}
```

Edit: can be used like this:

```
let user = get_by_id!(schema::users, User, pool, user_id)?;
```

Comment: Can you provide usage of this macro?
get_by_id!(schema::users::id, User)? Something like this?

Comment: I tried too: 
get_by_id!(user_table, User, get_by_id(connection, user_id));
I don't know how to call macro with function containing parameters.

Comment: @RfDzDeveloper I change the code so that It doesn't contain the function, using that function means that you have to define it in seperate module. Right now it is without function so you can use the macro directly as wrote it in the example usage